# Adding 'Next' and 'Previous' links on Google Custom Search (CSE)

Tags: javascript, search, google-custom-search

Is is possible to add Next and Previous links to the page results in Google Custom Search? I found this thread [How to show next/previous links in Google Custom Search Engine paging links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302495/how-to-show-next-previous-links-in-google-custom-search-engine-paging-links) but the code is for the older version of Google Custom Search.

The newer version just gives you a tag like `<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>` and everything gets generated from that. Any ideas? Thanks

This is how the search results are getting pulled in..

```
<script>
(function() {
    var cx = 'xxxxxx:xxxxx',
        gcse = document.createElement('script');

    gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Comment: The first step would probably be to add a gname attribute to your searchresults-only element so that you can access it in javascript.  IE: <gcse:searchresults-only gname="pickaname"></gcse:searchresults-only>

Then you can access the CSE via google.search.cse.element.getElement('pickaname')

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use the code from that link you posted; it relies on undocumented parameters that are liable to change.  I expect the better way would be to simply generate your own pagination and keep track of which page they're on your self.  You can use the searcher.gotoPage(page) function to change pages.  The only thing I'm not certain about is how to get the searcher object from the CSE element mentioned in my other comment, but you could try gsce_element.getWebSearcher() (where gsce_element is the results from the getElement call)

Comment: Finally, you might as well use the HTML-style tags.

References:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5
https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/reference#_class_GSearch

Personally I'm sticking with V1 until the V2 stuff is better documented though.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3302495/24267

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `searcher.cursor.currentPageIndex` and `searcher.gotoPage()` all of this wrapped in `google.setOnLoadCallback`

```
window.customSearchControl = customSearchControl;

$(function() {

    var link = $('<a />', {
        'html' : 'link',
        'href' : '#',
        'class' : 'general-button',
        'style' : 'margin-right:1em'
    });

    var searcher = window.customSearchControl.getWebSearcher();

    var prev = link.clone().click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var topage = searcher.cursor.currentPageIndex - 1;
        if(topage < 1) {
            topage = 0;
        }
        searcher.gotoPage(topage);
        return false;
    }).html('&lt; prev');

    var next = link.clone().click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var topage = searcher.cursor.currentPageIndex + 1;
        if(topage > searcher.cursor.pages.length) {
            topage = 10;
        }
        searcher.gotoPage(topage);
        return false;
    }).html('next &gt;');

    $('#cse').append(prev).append(next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some Jquery but can be done without. I put the explanations in the code.

```
 //Listens for DOM changes
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    makeNext();
});

// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true
});

function makeNext() {
    //Make a Next element
    var el = $("<div></div>", {
        "id": "next",
        "class": "gsc-cursor-page", // need google class so is same look and works with them
        "text": "Next",
        "on": { // on click, find what is the current page, and trigger click on the one after
            "click": function () {
                $(".gsc-cursor-current-page").next(".gsc-cursor-page").click();
            }
        }
    });
    //When results load, lots of changes are made, but we only wont 1 Next button
    if ($("#next").length == 0) {
        $(".gsc-cursor").append(el);
    }
}
```